# C++ base 10 to base 2 logic error

Tags: c++, logic, decimal, radix

I am doing a basic program to convert number from base 10 to base 2. I got this code:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int num=0, coc=0, res=0, div=0;
    printf ("Write a base 10 number\n");
    scanf ("%d", &num);
    div=num%2;
    printf ("The base 2 value is:\n");
    if(div==1)
    {
        coc=num/2;
        res=num%2;
        while(coc>=1)
        {
            printf ("%d", res);
            res=coc%2;
            coc=coc/2;
        }
        if(coc<1)
        {
            printf ("1");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("1");
         coc=num/2;
        res=num%2;
        while(coc>=1)
        {
            printf ("%d", res);
            res=coc%2;
            coc=coc/2;
        }
    }
    printf ("\n");
    system ("PAUSE");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Everything is good with certain numbers, but, if I try to convert the number 11 to base 2, I get 1101, if I try 56 I get 100011... I know is a logic problem and I am limited to basic algoritms and functions :(... any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://sscce.org).)

Comment: @computer yes i can use bitset.

Comment: @user2827058 please see an update

Answer (score 1):

you can use this, it is simpler and cleaner:. Use [`std::reverse`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse) from `<algorithm>` to reverse the result.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

string DecToBin(int number)
{
    string result = "";

    do
    {
        if ( (number & 1) == 0 )
            result += "0";
        else
            result += "1";

        number >>= 1;
    } while ( number );

    reverse(result.begin(), result.end());
    return result;
}
```

However even **much cleaner** version could be:

```
#include<bitset>

void binary(int i) {
    std::bitset<8*sizeof(int)> b = i;
    std::string s = b.to_string<char>();
    printf("\n%s",s.c_str());
}
```

using above, result of

```
binary(11);
binary(56);
```

is

> 00000000000000000000000000001011
>
> 00000000000000000000000000111000

### or even better:

```
#include <iostream>

void binary(int i) {
    std::bitset<8*sizeof(int)> b = i;//assume 8-bit byte,Stroustrup "C++..."&22.2
    std::cout<<b;
}
```